# How to create QGIS theme map?

Tags: qgis, thematic-map

I need to make theme map using diagrams like in MapInfo, can I do it in QGIS?
Or can I create a surface using attributes?

Answer (score 3):

Everything is in the Properties menu for each layer. You can create cartogram in Style bookmark (categorized, graduated or rule base cartograms). And creating cartodiagram is in  Diagram bookmark.

Comment: Thanks, I have found It.But I have a question. I used Diagram bookmark and want to make Diagrams visible in some range of scale. How can I do It? I have found there the visibility and set the min scale 1 and max 1000, but it doesn't work.
What can be wrong?